# Ansible Expect Module hung on attempting a simulated return keystroke

Tags: ansible

I would like to use the expect module in an ansible playbook to telnet through a termserver to reach a NetApp filer. I tried the telnet module, but using the port argument after the ip address doesn't seem to work.
Manually I would type the following:

```
[sansible@scspr0415857001 ansible]$ telnet 10.233.82.7 2033  
Trying 10.233.82.7...  
Connected to 10.233.82.7.  
Escape character is '^]'.  
Connected to port 33.  

login: admin  
Password:  

rtpsb-f6280-02a-1::>
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I think my issue is that the playbook is getting caught up on simulating a return keystroke after "Connected to port 33."

I've also tried using echo -ne '\n'

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:  
    - name: Expect Attempt  
      expect:  
        echo: yes  
        command: telnet 10.233.82.7 2033  
        responses:  
          Question:  
            - Connected to port* "echo"  
            - login: "admin"  
            - Password: "password"
```

The full traceback is:

```
  File "/tmp/ansible_piMb3N/ansible_module_expect.py", line 190, in main  
    encoding='utf-8')  

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {  
    "changed": true,  
    "cmd": "telnet 10.233.82.7 2033",  
    "delta": "0:00:30.122472",  
    "end": "2018-03-08 13:08:12.487220",  
    "invocation": {  
        "module_args": {  
            "chdir": null,  
            "command": "telnet 10.233.82.7 2033",  
            "creates": null,  
            "echo": true,  
            "removes": null,  
            "responses": {  
                "Question": [  
                    "Connected to port* \"echo\"",  
                    {  
                        "login": "admin"  
                    },  
                    {  
                        "Password": "password"  
                    }  
                ]  
            },  
            "timeout": 30  
        }  
    },  
    "msg": "non-zero return code",  
    "rc": 1,  
    "start": "2018-03-08 13:07:42.364748",  
    "stdout": "Trying 10.233.82.7...\r\r\nConnected to 10.233.82.7.\r\r\nEscape   character is '^]'.\r\r\nConnected to port 33. ",  
    "stdout_lines": [  
        "Trying 10.233.82.7...",  
        "",  
        "Connected to 10.233.82.7.",  
        "",  
        "Escape character is '^]'.",  
        "",  
        "Connected to port 33. "  
    ]  
}  
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/sansible/ansible/expect-r1.retry  

PLAY RECAP   *********************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The log indicates that it connected ok, to me it looks like the next pattern matching fails. Maybe try looking for the promt returned after the connection?

Comment: How do you edit to get rid of the stack exchange formatting?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. The "Question:" parameter needs to be omitted:
    ---
    - hosts: localhost
      connection: local
      gather_facts: false

```
  tasks:
    - name: Expect Attempt
      expect:
        echo: yes
        command: telnet 10.233.82.7 2033
        responses:
          Connected to port 33. :  "echo"
          login: "admin"
          Password: "password"
```